# How to connect to cakephp server with localhost:port from Android emulator?

Tags: android, cakephp

I am running the cakephp built in server `bin/cake server` which works fine for making requests through my laptop's browser: `localhost:8765/users/get/1`.

Yet when I try through my Android emulator to reach `10.0.2.2:8765/users/get/1` it just returns `10.0.2.2 refused to connect`.

If I turn off the cakephp server and use MAMP instead I can successfully reach my local server with `10.0.2.2:8888/ionic-backend/users/get/1`. So I know my emulator is setup correctly but does anyone know how to connect using cakephp's server? It would be much more convenient.

I am using a Mac, if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP Connection Refused in Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406105/cakephp-connection-refused-in-browser)